# Package `flowfram` - How do I query the width of the current frame?

Tags: layout, flowfram

I'm using a tabular within a frame, something along the lines of:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\newflowframe{0.5\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe{0.5\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.5\textwidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
    First thing & Second thing
\end{tabular}
\framebreak
\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}p{0.2\textwidth}}
    Third thing & Fourth thing
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Results in the following layout:
[image]

This is almost what I want, but notice how I'm using `0.2\textwidth` to specify the size of each tabular member. Instead, I'd like to be able to specify half of the frame's width, without having to define my own length for the purpose. Something along the lines of `0.4\framewidth` would be perfect. Is there any mechanism within the `flowfram` package that would allow me to query the current frame's width?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Try `\columnwidth`.  BTW, you might use `0.5\textwidth-0.5\columnsep` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\textwidth` is the width of the page minus the main margins, whereas `\columnwidth` is just the width of one the column of text (thus,  same that `\textwidth` in one column pages, but  some less of the half of `\textwidth` in two column pages).

But in other contexts (the cell of a table of a table, a minipage, a nested list, etc.) the width of text could less than `\textwidth` or `\columnwidth`. Here what you want is the width of the line  (i.e., `\linewidth`) that will work equally well also in one or two column texts (i.e, it could be equal to `\textwidth` and/or `\columnwidth`, ..or not).

Therefore, the "safest" is to use table columns with widths always relatives to `\linewidth`. If you want a `p{}` column of about the 50% of the frame, then `p{0.5\linewidth}` is near to your goal, **but**:

1. You must take also into account the separations between columns (`\tabcolsep`).
2. The  tabular is placed like a big alphabet character. That is, after a blank line is like a big first letter of a paragraph, so indented by default. Therefore, you should use `\noindent`, or alternatively, set `\parindent` to `0pt` to avoid the indentation of the table.

The MWE:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{flowfram}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\newflowframe{0.5\textwidth}{\textheight}{0pt}{0pt}
\newflowframe{0.5\textwidth}{\textheight}{0.5\textwidth}{0pt}

\begin{document}

\tabcolsep1em

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
    First thing & Second thing \\\hline
\end{tabular}

\framebreak

\noindent\begin{tabular}{|p{\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|p{\dimexpr 0.5\linewidth-2\tabcolsep}|}
    Third thing & Fourth thing \\\hline
\end{tabular}


\end{document}
```

Note:

The  tabulars has been "jailed" only to better check the widths of the four cells. Not al all a suggestion of style ...

Note: You may want take a look to the `tabularx` package to simplify  the tabulars to some like:

```
\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
    First thing & Second thing \\
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: Thanks. This gives me a lot more context into sizes. I'd never heard of columnwidth.